# Tracking frame.origin.x in UIPageController while scrolling

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using standard `UIPageViewController` here and I need to track x coordinate in order to change the alpha of the image accordingly. I try to find the `UIScrollView` in `UIPageViewController` like this and it works:

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        [(UIScrollView *)view setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

But when I do this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    MTWPageContentViewController *pageContentVC = [self viewControllerAtIndex:_mainPageControl.currentPage];
    NSLog(@"%f", pageContentVC.view.frame.origin.x);
}
```

`NSLog` gives me 0.000 which obviously means that I'm doing something wrong.

`pageContentVC` exists and it is the view controller visible at the moment I scroll.
So, tell me how do I track x coordinate of `UIPageViewController`'s subview while scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the gesture recognisers from the `UIPageViewController` and add yourself as a target/action to get information about the pan.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:UIPanGestureRecognizer.class]) {
    [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(panned:)];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So, how do I get the x coordinate using the gesture recogniser?